# Pandas: Groupby and cut within a group

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
userid   name       date
1           name1    2016-06-04
1           name2    2016-06-05
1           name3    2016-06-04
1           name1    2016-06-06
2           name23   2016-06-01
2           name2    2016-06-01
3           name1    2016-06-03
3           name6    2016-06-03
3           name12   2016-06-03
3           name65   2016-06-04
```

So, I want to retain only the rows of the users till the first date events, and cut the rest.

The final df would be as follows:

```
userid   name       date
1           name1    2016-06-04
1           name2    2016-06-04
2           name23   2016-06-01
2           name2    2016-06-01
3           name1    2016-06-03
3           name6    2016-06-03
3           name12   2016-06-03



userid     int64
name      object
time      object
```

The `type()` of data points in the time column is a `datetime.date`

So, the tasks would involve `grouping with respect to userid`, `sorting according to the date`, then `retaining only the rows with first(/earliest) date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first sort `DataFrame` by column `date` by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - get all rows where is first values:

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
       .groupby('userid')
       .apply(lambda x: x[x.date == x.date.iloc[0]])
       .reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
   userid    name       date
0       1   name1 2016-06-04
1       1   name3 2016-06-04
2       2  name23 2016-06-01
3       2   name2 2016-06-01
4       3   name1 2016-06-03
5       3   name6 2016-06-03
6       3  name12 2016-06-03
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)  I was trying to sort on the groupby object :D

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!